# how base64 converts characters that aren't existing in its character list?

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, utf-8, base64

I have a script that generates encrypted texts with random encoding each time. To save the encrypted texts in the database with utf-8 encoding I converted the encrypted text to base64 encode. I think it converted correctly, the generated strings may be like `( ÷§úAû‰ñÁyˆÚªÌE)`.

How did base64 encoding convert the strange encrypted text although the  encrypted text has characters that aren't existing in base64 encode character set (`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/`)?

For reference of base64 encode character list, here's the associated [RFC](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt).

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: look sir , i provided in my post a sample of encrypted string that has characters not existing in the base64 encode , and it encodes it successfully altough these chars aren't existing there , do i have to imagine that the base64 encode converts it firstly to binary then from binary to ASCII?

Comment: All data is binary. Including text. A computer only deals in binary data. Base64 encodes this binary into different binary, namely binary which represents ASCII characters. You may want to start here: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: ok i will , but do you mean that when i write base64_Encode(example) , the base64 encode sees that as a binary data then it process it to ASCII ? or it converts it firstly to binary or what is the right sir ?

Comment: Where you *see* text like `"abc"`, that text is *actually* represented by the bytes `0x61 0x62 0x63`. Base 64 encodes *those bytes* to the bytes `0x59 0x57 0x4A 0x6A`, which, when interpreted as ASCII, represent the characters "YWJj".

Comment: @mina It doesn't convert anything to binary. The input *is* binary.

Comment: @deceze -Biffen : Thanks For Both OF you , I am Appreciating your help  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 is for encoding *any* binary data into valid ASCII. The data that you encode does *not* have to be in the Base64 character set (that would make the whole operation rather useless).

Base64 simply takes the binary data byte for byte<sup>1</sup> and maps the bits into combinations of its characters. Thus there are no other requirements of the input than that it consists of bytes.

In the case of `÷§úAû‰ñÁyˆÚªÌE`, it would be converted like so:

You say the input is in UTF-8<sup>2</sup>, so the bytes would be `C3 B7 C2 A7 C3 BA 41 C3 BB E2 80 B0 C3 B1 C3 81 79 CB 86 C3 9A C2 AA C3 8C 45` (that's `÷§úAû‰ñÁyˆÚªÌE` in UTF-8).

So take the first three bytes (`C3 B7 C2`) and map them:

```
Byte   | C3              | B7              | C2              |
Bits   | 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 | 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 | 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 |
Index  | 48         | 59          | 31          | 2          |
Base64 | w          | 7           | f           | C          |
```

Thus the first four characters are `w7fC`. Then just repeat for the rest of the input (if the input is not in a multiple of three bytes, then some padding is done, not covered here).

As you can see, the input can be *any* binary data.

---

<sup>1</sup> Base64 uses 8-bit bytes.

<sup>2</sup> UTF-8, luckily, uses 8-bit code units.

---

<sup>You can read more about the details of how the encoding is done on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).</sup>

Comment: i provided in my post a sample of encrypted string (not binary data) ,  that has characters not existing in the base64 encode , and it encodes it successfully altough these chars aren't existing there , do i have to imagine that the base64 encode converts it firstly to binary then from binary to ASCII?

Comment: var_dump(base64_encode("šþJ‰ßÙ’Ñã[§½Vº-%-”….9siéæÚøã$");   this is my php code , it works fine although the characters aren't existing in the character list .

Comment: @mina Once again: The input does *not* have to consist of ‘Base64 characters’. The encoding deals with the bits of the input. The *whole point* of Base64 is to be able to encode *any* binary data to (printable) ASCII characters.

Comment: your answer is ideal for me , so you mean that base64 encode deals with the bytes of the input . but you wrote above that the string in utf-8 so the memory converts it to bytes to save it . this also ideal , but who did convert the utf-8 to binary or bytes when base64 called ? i think you are close to make me understand completely the problem

Comment: @mina *You* said that the input was in UTF-8. UTF-8 is a *binary* format. *No-one* converts *anything* to binary.

Comment: sir , I am appreciating your time for answering me Thank you firstly  , and i will start studying  your provided articles .